# Entity Framework when object is added then its reference is added or what

Tags: entity-framework

This question may sound silly but I was trying to find out a method where bulk operation is done through EF. I know it is not a good practice.

During search I found this link
https://github.com/geersch/EntityFrameworkBulkCopy

It has given an example

```
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        var entity = new Contact
                            {
                                CustomerId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                FirstName = "Ruben",
                                LastName = "Geers",
                                EmailAddress = "geersch@gmail.com"
                            };

        context.Contacts.AddObject(entity);
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```

My question as you see we are adding objects in loop and according to me object is a reference pointer when every time a new object is created

```
         var entity = new Contact
```

wont it will be create trouble means you added a reference of an object, then its being recreated.

Bit confused ...

Comment: Recreation will not replace original reference. Constructor creates a new object (allocation in memory) and returns "pointer" to that value. When you pass reference as argument to the method you are passing that address (you are passing it by value).

Comment: @LadislavMrnka when object is passed in method then automatically it byref dont you think so. Like I pass obj in method made some changes and then when i check values of it in calling method i find changes

Comment: Yes but if the method doesn't change the value of the object but instead assign another object to the parameter this change will not be visible outside of the method. ByVal and ByRef differs in what is placed on the stack when the method is called. If you pass parameter ByVal the data are placed to the stack so the change to data doesn't affect outer scope. If you pass parameter ByRef (all objects) only the pointer value is placed on the stack - any changes to address (the value of the pointer) in either the method or outer scope are independent.

Comment: It is visible I tried I create object and passed it to method, in method I changed the values and its got reflected as well in calle method as well.

Comment: Don't change value of the object, change the reference itself by assigning another object - that is equivalent of the problem you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact not recreating the object.

```
   for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {

      var entity = new Contact

     //rest of code omnitted
```

Notes that the reference entity is being declared *within the scope of the for-loop*

This means that for each iteration a *new* object is being declared. It has the same name as it's precessors, but not the same pointer.

I don't know this - but im pretty sure that the name of the variable is not directly used as a memory pointer. (thats a guess thought)